# Iterating over keys instead of values Vue app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I'm trying to select the values for three keys from my api with axios.
Each time I make a request I'm displaying the values four times for each key. I dropped a key from my data models and I re tested. When I did that my request displayed three times instead of four. Meaning I'm iterating over the keys instead of the values.

How Can I change this code to display only the values of each key? I am using nuxt django and axios.

This is the json data axios returns.
`{"id":1,"balance":10.0,"exposure":7.0,"free_funds":80.0}`

How do I just get the values **only** for each paragraph tag instead of the values for each paragraph tag 4 times?

```
  <template>
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Current Balance</h2>
      <ul class="trendings">
        <li v-for="result in results" :key="result">
          <p>{{ results.balance }} balance</p>
          <p>{{ results.free_funds }} free_funds</p>
          <p>{{ results.exposure }} exposure</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </template>


  <script>
  import axios from "axios";
  export default {
    asyncData() {
      return axios.get("http://localhost:8000/api/balance/1").then(res => {
        return { results: res.data };
      });
    }
  };
  </script>
```

Comment: @ChrisLi I just want to display the value of balance, exposure and free_funds in the paragraph tags I tried to result.balance and I got back no values. Just the keys 4 times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the JSON response looks exactly like this:

```
{"id":1,"balance":10.0,"exposure":7.0,"free_funds":80.0}
```

Then you don't even need the `v-for` because there is only one thing to iterate over.

If you want a `v-for`, force the data to come back as an array by wrapping it so that it would be this:

```
[ {"id":1,"balance":10.0,"exposure":7.0,"free_funds":80.0} ]
```

So:

```
return { results: [res.data] };
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and solution. This has fixed my issue. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

See the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-an-Object)

```
 <li v-for="(result, key) in results" :key="result">
      <p>{{ result }} {{ key }}</p>
 </li>
```

Comment: I thought this too, but it isn't relevant.  The issue is that response is an Object and the OP thinks that they need to iterate over a bare Object.